# Ordering Django form fields with exclude

Tags: python, django, forms

Django 1.9+ allows me to specify the order of a `ModelForm`'s fields by passing a list to `field_order`. But it doesn't work if I have `exclude` in my form's `Meta` class:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ['unwanted_field1', 'unwanted_field2']
        field_order = ['foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs']
```

(I get the fields in the order they are defined in the model). If I specify the fields I want instead of using `exclude`, they are ordered the way I want:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs']
```

So how should one use `field_order`?

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave my own solution to this here in case anyone else trips up in the same way. It seems that `field_order` is an attribute of the `ModelForm` class, not of its `Meta` class (for some reason: explanations welcome...). Therefore, the following works as intended:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):

    field_order = ['foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs']

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ['unwanted_field1', 'unwanted_field2']
```